# Eclipse to Android Studio Migration and Build: 300+ projects and one common library project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have a little more than 300 android projects created in Eclipse. Each of these projects references one single library project also created in eclipse.

Currently all of these projects are in a single workspace. What would be the best way to import all of these in one shot to Android Studio keeping the reference of each project to the library project intact?

Also, I have written a batch file to do and build to create release apks for all 300+ apps with one click. Would something similar be possible in Android Studio? i.e. will i be able to create all 300+ apks at once. I would grow old by the time i finish if i do it one by one for each of the apps.

Another important question: Can i have all the 300+ projects as well as the library project as modules in Android studio inside a single project and is it possible to create multiple apks this way by using the single project?

Any suggestions that can help would be highly appreciated.

**The library project contains all activities and logic. The other 300 apps referencing this library project merely changes package names, assets and resources.**

Thanks

Comment: you would have to import every single project to "transform" them into Android Studio project. The main library need to be imported too and added as "dependencies". BTW... forget about the idea to have 300 projects in one visual workspace. Android Studio use 1 Android Studio window for each project.

Comment: Thanks! But, why the vote down? Was there something wrong about my doubt? :)

Comment: From what you say i think I'll need to stick to Eclipse for these projects at least till the time Android Studio provisions this or some angel knows of a workaround. :-(

Comment: Is more a "how to do this" question and is taking as "off topic". "Google it first" is what everyone would tell you (and SO too) because it doesn't show any effort to search the issue and simply searching for help here. EDIT: Also is taking as "opinion-based" question (also off topic)

Comment: I did try searching and also trying to import and to find ways but with no gain. Hence thought it would require some research to make it work. Also, this is an issue that many are facing (as i understand from google search) I would happily delete the question from here if anyone else also feels the same way about this query. Thanks for the help though :-)

Comment: no problem ;) good luck with the 300 projects thing lol maybe some good google forums with some google engineers have better workarounds to that. (you can find those guys over Google+)

Answer (score 0):

product flavors was a solution in my case, with a bit of modifications to the structures (since all my logic and layouts were in the library project). What changed across the 300 projects were resources and assets only and that was easy to configure using product flavors in build.gradle and make it ONE project with 300 flavors. (took a while but worked like charm)

Although this fixed my problem and i was able to make it work, I will not accept this answer. Posting it here just in case someone in a similar situation might benefit from it.

Would still want to learn if there is a way to generate multiple apks using the same project (not using product flavors, of course).